# I want to get $username variable from another page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, fetch

This is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("#send").click (function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    alert (username);
    $.ajax({
        url : "sendpost.php",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {username},
        success: function(datat){}
        })
    });
});
```

This is my php code

```
include ('connection_socio.php');
if(isset($_POST['body']))
{
    $body=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['body']);
    $date_added="123";
    $added_by="123";
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $check = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result_profile = mysqli_query($db, $check);    
    //check whether the no of rows in users table is more than 0

    //get username from database
    $getusername = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_profile);
    $user_posted_to = $username;
    echo $user_posted_to;
    $query_post = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('', '$user_poste_to',)";                  
    mysqli_query($db, $query_post);
    echo "POSTED SUUCESSFULLY";
}
```

This is my profile.php code:

```
if (isset($_GET['u']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['u']);
    //checks and remove symbols like # , ' etc
    if(ctype_alnum($username))
    {
        //check user existance
        $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result_profile = mysqli_query($db, $check);    
        //check whether the no of rows in users table is more than 0
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result_profile) == 1)
        {
            //get username from database
            $getusername = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_profile);
            $username = $getusername['username'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "User dont exist";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

what I want is to fetch variable `$username` from `profile.php` page and assign it to `$user_posted_to` variable in `senpost.php` page and insert into database using javascript if any expert can help will really appreciate it i have tried `this.attr()` but thats not working also `this.value` is also not working I'm unable to fetch username from that page can anyone help me with this the username variable i want to fetch is the username of the user profile which I want to assign to `$user_poste_to`

Comment: Please psot the HTML from where you click the "send"

Comment: Ok I will post it in a while

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the best way to access the value of $username is to store it to a [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp), once you are in senpost.php, all you need to do is to get the cookie you stored and assign it to $user_posted_to variable. the correct way to get the value of a textbox/form element in by using this $(input[type="text"]).val()

Comment: Thanks for the answer I figured out the problem I can store that variable to a session same as I did for login session thanks for letting me know.many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Update your AJax call.

```
data: {username:username},
```

here first username will be the index and 2nd username will be the variable which you got using `$(this).val()`

Comment: I updated it but it says undefined index since it is not fetching from a text field